# R Shiny display output externally hosted image

Tags: r, shiny

I have a Shiny app that returns a character string containing the direct URL to an image hosted on the web. I am trying to find a way to display this image directly as an output.

When using renderImage() with src = "image url" the app does not display the image.

Here is an example of the problem:

ui.R

```
library(shiny)

shinyUI(fluidPage(
  headerPanel("render externally hosted Image example"),

  mainPanel(
   # Use imageOutput to place the image on the page
   imageOutput("myImage")
  )
))
```

server.R

```
library(shiny)

shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  output$myImage <- renderImage({
    list(src = "http://data-informed.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/R-language-logo-224x136.png",
     contentType = 'image/png',
     width = 224,
     height = 136,
     alt = "This is image alternate text")
  })
})
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 14):

You could use `htmlOutput()` in the ui and `renderText()` in server.

Server.r

```
src = "https://theWeb/aPictureSomewhere.jpg"
output$picture<-renderText({c('<img src="',src,'">')})
```

ui.r

```
htmlOutput("picture")
```

Comment: I tried this for my issue, and it renders the image, but it doesn't work in combination with my clickable image code. If you can help, that would be great. Find the post here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45709189/renderimage-from-url-and-clickable