# How to load external image to Shiny

Tags: r, image, shiny

In my current project, I am trying to load images to `shiny dashboard` using `R`. The code snippet is as shown below:

```
dashboardBody(
          hr(),
          fluidRow(
            column(6,align="center",imageOutput("ginger"))
          )
        )
      )

      server <- function(input, output) { 
        output$ginger <- renderImage({
          return(list(
            src = "images/ginger.jpg",
            contentType = "image/jpeg",
            width = 300,
            height = 200,
            alt = "Face"
          ))
        }, deleteFile = FALSE)
```

Basically, it just display the image on the `shiny dashboard`. Here the image is stored in the local machine. Now, I want to load image from google drive or from the web. I am trying to load the image from my google drive and URL is https://drive.google.com/file/d/0By6SOdXnt-LFaDhpMlg3b3FiTEU/view.

**I could not able to figure out that how to load images from google drive or web in shiny and how to add title in the image also?**  **Am I missing something?**

Comment: probably a stupid question but is your image in the www folder?

Comment: @Daniel- Image could be in the google drive and may on the web also.

Comment: @saursabh13 so your 'src = "images/ginger.jpg"' is just a dummy?, k, misunderstood your question, sry : (

Comment: @Daniel- That way is fine. If the image is located in the local machine in the images folder then it displays image to the dashboard. But I want to load an image from the web also in this case image is not located in the local machine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35651669/r-shiny-display-output-externally-hosted-image) is instructive. Here's a barebones `shiny` app with an external image call to display the image that you mention on your Google Drive account.

```
library(shiny)

# Define UI with external image call
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Look at the image below"),

  sidebarLayout(sidebarPanel(),

                mainPanel(htmlOutput("picture"))))

# Define server with information needed to hotlink image
server <- function(input, output) {
  output$picture <-
    renderText({
      c(
        '<img src="',
        "http://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=0By6SOdXnt-LFaDhpMlg3b3FiTEU",
        '">'
      )
    })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Thanks @Andrew. But how to add the titles to images. Here you have added the title as titlePanle but how to add titles if we have multiple images?

Comment: It's not working for me. I tried it by providing the drive and dropbox image urls but images are not getting rendered.

Comment: @AbhinandanSatpute- Have you tried using any image from google? Bcoz I was also facing the same issue with drive and Dropbox.

Comment: For me this did not work locally, but worked once I deployed the app.