# Display Google Drive Image In RShiny Using Service Account

Tags: r, shiny, google-api, google-drive-api

Feel like I might be missing something here. I am looking to display images from my google drive in a shiny app using the url. I am planning on accessing the images from my drive using a service account. The simple code I have for this is below. The file id is left blank in the url here.

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
library(googledrive)

drive_auth(path = "client-secret.json")

ui <- fluidPage(
  h4("Embedded image"),
  uiOutput("img")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$img <- renderUI({
    tags$img(src = "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=   #image_id#   ") 
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

The link that I am using is fine if I make it public; however due to security issues, I thought I could access a private link with my service account in my google project. I have accessed sheets so many times using a [similar approach to this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vISRn5qFrkM). So I really thought this would be a no brainer

What I have done so far:

- Added the Google Drive API to my project
- Created the Service Account and gave it editor permissions
- Shared access to the file folder for the service account
- Made sure I am using https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id= to access the image
- Tried both png and jpg file types

This yielded nothing. To check my sanity I went ahead and made sure I could access googlesheets with that service account in a similar manner.

```
gs4_auth(path = "client-secret.json")
URL <- #Sheet url
read_sheet(URL,sheet="Sheet1")
```

This works fine as expected with the service account. I am not 100% sure what the difference is or if I can even load a private image (with service account added as editor to folder and images).

Any input is appreciated here while I keep working on this.

Comment: Where did you get that endpoint?   I would think you should be usinghttps://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/fileId/export

Comment: @DaImTo that endpoint came from [this post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43322327/how-to-load-external-image-to-shiny). It still seems to work well with a public image. Looking into the method you prescribe [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/export) it seems to have trouble for both the export and the get outside of the google workspace. Which means when attempting to load the image I have no luck in shiny

Answer (score 1):

Although it is not a direct method, you can access drive files via google cloud storage buckets and a service account to display them in Shiny. You need to use the Drive API in apps script and Google Cloud Storage. A full walkthrough of google cloud storage and uploading an image via apps script can be found [here](https://www.labnol.org/code/20074-upload-files-to-google-cloud-storage). From there you need a service account associated with your cloud project. I gave mine Storage admin and service account token creator permissions.

Once you upload your file into your Google Cloud storage bucket, you can then access the file in r

This is an example Shiny app that displays an image from a Google Cloud Storage bucket. The app uses the googleCloudStorageR package to authenticate and download the image file, and the EBImage package to read and display the image.

```
#First, we define the necessary libraries and authenticate with our Google Cloud Storage account:


library(shiny)
library(googleCloudStorageR)
library(EBImage)

# Set the path to the service account key file
key_file <- "path/to/key/file.json"

# Authenticate with Google Cloud Storage
gcs_auth(key_file)
#Next, we define the user interface with a single output element for the image


ui <- fluidPage(
  displayOutput("outputId")
)
#Then, we define the server function that retrieves the image from the Google Cloud Storage bucket and renders it in the UI:


server <- function(input, output) {
  # Retrieve the image from the Google Cloud Storage bucket
  image_file <- gcs_get_object(bucket = "my-bucket", object_name = "my-image.png")
  
  # Convert the binary image data to an EBImage object
  image <- image_file %>% Image(colormode = "Color")
  
  # Display the image in the UI
  output$outputId <- renderDisplay({
    display(image, all = TRUE)
  })
}
#Finally, we run the app:

shinyApp(ui, server)
#This code can be modified to download and display other types of files from a Google Cloud Storage bucket, and to display them in a different way depending on the data type.
```

From there the image displays and can be interacted with. It is not a direct answer to my own question, but it shows how it can be done. The bucket is set to private and the images should stay secure this way.