# RenderImage from URL and clickable

Tags: html, r, url, shiny, render

I would like to figure out how to use renderImage in Shiny with online located images (URL), and make the image clickable, so that I can hang an observeEvent() to it. I can do both these things, but not together. My approach to render an URL doesn't work with clicking, and the local image version that allows clicking doesn't render URL images.

Here are the two half working versions: 
I took some inspiration from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35651669/r-shiny-display-output-externally-hosted-image) for the

## Clickable

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
        imageOutput("image1", click = "MyImage")
  )

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  setwd(Set the directory of the image in here)    #### modify to test
  output$image1 <- renderImage({
    list(
      src = "YOUR_IMAGE.png",                     #### modify to test
      contentType = "image/png",
      width = 90,
      height = 78,
      alt = "This is alternate text"
    )}, deleteFile = FALSE)
  observeEvent(input$MyImage, { print("Hey there")})
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

if I put an URL in  (and remove the deleteFile = FALSE) it shows an empty square. still clickable though.

## URLable by using `renderUI()`

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
           uiOutput("image1", click = "MyImage")
  )

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  setwd(AppDir)

  output$image1<- renderUI({
    imgurl2 <- "https://www.rstudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/RStudio-Logo-Blue-Gradient.png"
    tags$img(src=imgurl2, width = 200, height = 100)
  })
 observeEvent(input$MyImage, { print("Hey there")})
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

shows the image, but the image isn't clickable anymore.

If I change `renderUI()` and `uiOuput()` into `renderImage()` and `imageOutput()` in example 2, it throws a 'invalid file argument' error.

## htmlOuput with renderText

I also tried this version that was in the other SO post, but again, not clickable. This approach is based on the answer on this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43322327/how-to-load-external-image-to-shiny?noredirect=1&lq=1)

```
 library(shiny)

  ui <- fluidPage(
    htmlOutput("image1", click = "MyImage")
  )

  server <- function(input, output, session) {
    setwd(AppDir)
    imgurl2 <- "https://www.rstudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/RStudio-Logo-Blue-Gradient.png"

    output$image1<- renderText({c('<img src="',imgurl2,'">')})

    observeEvent(input$MyImage, { print("Hey there")})
  }
  shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I want to move away from local images because that seems to make more sense once we publish the Shiny App. So therefore really in need of a solution that allows rendering of URL images and have them being clickable. Bonus points if somebody can explain why the `click =` only works local files with imageOutput.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One alternative is to use the `onclick` function from `shinyjs` library. It allows you to include click events to specific html elements (targeted by id).

[Here's the documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/shinyjs/versions/0.0.7.0/topics/onclick)

In your case the code would look like this:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),
  uiOutput("image1", click = "MyImage")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  output$image1<- renderUI({
    imgurl2 <- "https://www.rstudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/RStudio-Logo-Blue-Gradient.png"

    div(id = "myImage",
      tags$img(src = imgurl2, width = 200, height = 100)
    )
  })
  onclick(
    myImage, 
    { 
      # Do whatever you want!
      print("Hey there")
    }
  )
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: In addition, take a look [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/content/images/) if you want to better adjust the image position. Shiny offers a bit of useful bootstrap features.

Answer (score 0):

What about transforming image from url into a ggplot as:

```
library(magick)
library(cowplot)
library(gtools)
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  uiOutput("myplotoutput"),
  uiOutput("text")  
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$myplotoutput = renderUI( {
    plotOutput("urlimage", click=clickOpts(id="myclick") )
}  )

output$text=renderUI({
    validate(
      need(try(!invalid(input$myclick)), "Text will appear here")
    )
    textOutput("reactext")
})

output$reactext<-renderText(mytext$texto)

output$urlimage<- renderPlot({
g<-  ggdraw() +   draw_image("https://jeroen.github.io/images/frink.png")
g
})

mytext<-reactiveValues()  

observeEvent(input$myclick, {
    mytext$texto<-"Hey there"
})
} 

shinyApp(ui, server)
```