# How to use markers to call out points on an image in Shiny R?

Tags: r, image, shiny, leaflet, coordinates

I am currently working on a simple shiny app in R that is supposed to display an image of a fantasy map. That in itself is pretty simple, but I'd like to be able to place markers on the image, that display some text when clicked on.

This is fairly simple to do using Leaflet in R when using real maps (see: https://rstudio.github.io/leaflet/markers.html), but I have no idea how to do this with a simple .png image. I assume I have to encode coordinates onto the image, but I don't know if that is possible.

This is my code so far (the image is called oondir_map.png)

```
# app.R
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Image Display App with Dropdown"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("dropdown_select", "Select Option:",
                  choices = c("B1", "B2", "B3"),
                  selected = "B1"),
      textOutput("selected_text"),
      width = 2
    ),
    mainPanel(
      imageOutput("image")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$image <- renderImage({
    list(src = "oondir_map.png",
         contentType = "image/png",
         width = 800, height = 600, alt = "Oondir Map")
  }, deleteFile = FALSE)
  
  output$selected_text <- renderText({
    paste("You selected:", input$dropdown_select)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

All advice is appreciated!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For the overlay, you will likely need to find CSS or similar to put the image  in the background, I don't have a suggestion for that atm. However, once you have that, you might be able to use https://stackoverflow.com/a/56941603/3358272 for registering clicks on an image (untested);  if the first (accepted) answer doesn't work, one of the other answers there suggests  using `cowplot::draw_image` on a `ggplot()` blank canvas, which will allow you to use its `plot_click` and similar callbacks (see https://mastering-shiny.org/action-graphics.html#interactivity).

Comment: Not sure if someone has made an effort to package https://leafletjs.com/examples/crs-simple/crs-simple.html for R as a Leflet extra, but you can check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47170828/overlay-image-on-r-leaflet-map and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60160039/adding-just-an-arbitrary-image-to-a-leaflet-map on how to achieve this though `htmlwidgets::onRender()` and js.